# Express assets served through wildcard route

Tags: node.js, express

I've got a strange bug in my MEAN application whereby asset files are being served through my wildcard route.

I want to serve a single HTML file via express and let Angular take care of all the routing etc. That route is setup like so (defined after middleware):

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./app/www/index.html');
});
```

I'm using the express static middleware which is setup like this:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + './app/www'));
```

My project structure (simplified):

```
app
-- /www
---- /assets
---- index.html
app.js
```

When I load assets/app.js in the browser I see the code inside index.html. Why is the static middleware being ignored?

Comment: If you're diagram is correct, "assets/app.js" doesn't exist, so `express.static` skips the request and the catchall sends index.html

Comment: @Amit why would it not exist?

Comment: in your diagram, the only "app.js" is next to the "app" dicrectory. Your static looks for files under "/app/www", and it's not there

Comment: @Amit so now this is a new issue.. I'm using webpack so for some reason express isn't loading assets/app.js

Comment: 1. change/delete the question, it's no longer relevant. 2. your comment doesn't make sense to me, sorry (but I'm not familiar with webpack so...)